# Prevent process from opening new file descriptor on Linux but allow receiving file descriptors via sockets

Tags: c, linux, system-calls

I'm currently working on a project where I have a parent process that sets up a socketpair, forks and then uses this socketpair to communicate. The child, if it wants to open a file (or any other file descriptor based resource) should always go to the parent, request the resource and get the `fd` sent via the socketpair. Furthermore I want to prevent the child from opening any file descriptor by itself.

I stumbled over `setrlimit` which successfully prevents the child from opening new file descriptors, but it also seems to invalidate any file descriptors sent over the initial socket connection. Is there any method on Linux that allows a single process to open any file, send its file descriptor to other processes and lets them use them without allowing these other processes to open any file descriptor by themselves?

For my use case that can be any kernel configuration, system call, etc. as long as it can be applied after fork and as long as it applies to all file descriptors (not just files but also sockets, socketpairs, etc.).

Comment: You might be interested in seccomp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you have here is exactly the use case of [seccomp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seccomp).

Using seccomp, you can filter syscalls in different ways. What you want to do in this situation is, right after `fork()`, to install a `seccomp` filter that disallows the use of `open(2)`, `openat(2)`, `socket(2)` (and more).
To accomplish this, you can do the following:

1. First, create a seccomp context using [`seccomp_init(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_init.3.html) with the default behavior of `SCMP_ACT_ALLOW`.
2. Then add a rule to the context using [`seccomp_rule_add(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_rule_add.3.html) for each syscall that you want to deny. You can use `SCMP_ACT_KILL` to kill the process if the syscall is attempted, `SCMP_ACT_ERRNO(val)` to make the syscall fail returning the specified `errno` value, or any other `action` value defined in the manual page.
3. Load the context using [`seccomp_load(3)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/seccomp_load.3.html) to make it effective.

##### IMPORTANT!

Note that a blacklist approach like this one is in general weaker than a whitelist approach. It allows any syscall that is not explicitly disallowed, and **could result in a bypass of the filter**. If you believe that the child process you want to execute could be maliciously trying to avoid the filter, or if you already know which syscalls will be needed by the children, a whitelist approach is better, and you should do the opposite of the above: create filter with the default action of `SCMP_ACT_KILL` and allow the needed syscalls with `SCMP_ACT_ALLOW`. In terms of code the difference is minimal (the whitelist is probably longer, but the steps are the same).

---

Here's an example of the above (I'm doing `exit(-1)` in case of error just for simplicity's sake):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <seccomp.h>

static void secure(void) {
    int err;
    scmp_filter_ctx ctx;

    int blacklist[] = {
        SCMP_SYS(open),
        SCMP_SYS(openat),
        SCMP_SYS(creat),
        SCMP_SYS(socket),
        SCMP_SYS(open_by_handle_at),
        // ... possibly more ...
    };

    // Create a new seccomp context, allowing every syscall by default.
    ctx = seccomp_init(SCMP_ACT_ALLOW);
    if (ctx == NULL)
        exit(-1);

    /* Now add a filter for each syscall that you want to disallow.
       In this case, we'll use SCMP_ACT_KILL to kill the process if it
       attempts to execute the specified syscall. */

    for (unsigned i = 0; i < sizeof(blacklist) / sizeof(blacklist[0]); i++) {
        err = seccomp_rule_add(ctx, SCMP_ACT_KILL, blacklist[i], 0);
        if (err)
            exit(-1);
    }

    // Load the context making it effective.
    err = seccomp_load(ctx);
    if (err)
        exit(-1);

    seccomp_release(ctx);
}
```

Now, in your program, you can call the above function to apply the seccomp filter right after the `fork()`, like this:

```
child_pid = fork();
if (child_pid == -1)
    exit(-1);

if (child_pid == 0) {
    secure();

    // Child code here...

    exit(0);
} else {
    // Parent code here...
}
```

A few important notes on seccomp:

- A seccomp filter, once applied, cannot be removed or altered by the process.
- If `fork(2)` or `clone(2)` are allowed by the filter, any child processes will be constrained by the same filter.
- If `execve(2)` is allowed, the existing filter will be preserved across a call to `execve(2)`.
- If the `prctl(2)` syscall is allowed, the process is able to apply further filters.

Comment: Blacklisting for a sandbox? Generally a bad idea, you want whitelisting instead.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know, but a whitelist approach does not apply to OP's situation very well since they just want to disallow opening new file descriptors. I will add a note at the end.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's what I need. A whitelist is indeed better for the application I originally intended. I just didn't have in mind that there are more things one should restrict than just opening file descriptors.

Comment: @jklmnn yeah, exactly. I indeed just forgot that `socket(2)` can also create a `fd`, so that should be blocked too. If you know the child process a whitelist approach is better.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli A whitelist is definitely better.  Offhand, `creat()`, `dup()`, and `dup2()` are all Linux system calls that return file descriptors.  There are a lot of ways around a blacklist...

Comment: @AndrewHenle totally right, I'm adding `creat` above; `dup` seemed ok per OP's question.  Anyway, of course the point of whitelist being better than blacklist still stands. Thanks.